# Enumerate ViewControllers located in stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Next button is not working. It throws an error `Application tried to present modally an active controller` What should i do to enumerate through array of `ViewControllers` when i press `next` button. I have read many threads regarding the same problem but could not figure out the solution. Thanks in advance!

.h file

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tab;
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)newTab:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    myViewController *newTab = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
    if (![newTab isBeingPresented]) {
        [self presentViewController:newTab animated:YES completion:nil];

        [tab addObject:newTab];
}
}
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {

    [tab enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {


        [self presentViewController:tab[idx] animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];    }




- (IBAction)prev:(id)sender {

    for (i=[tab count]; i>0; i--) {
    if (![self  isBeingDismissed]){
    [tab[i-1] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        ;
}}}
```

Comment: you cannot present the same view controller again without dismissing it.Will creating new instance be a problem for you or thats what you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the ViewControllers present in stack

```
NSArray * controllerArray = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];

for (UIViewController *controller in controllerArray){
    //Code here.. e.g. print their titles to see the array setup;
    NSLog(@"%@",controller.title);
    if ([controller.title isEqual:@"Title1"]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

On selecting Next button enumerate through the Views present in stack and check for the title and do that specific operation needed for that view. Above i have added the code to popViewController if the title matches.

Hope it helps.